# How to post file object in angular?

Tags: angular, http

I am getting `file` as `File`. How can I pass `file` in `url`?

```
 importData(repoId: string, file: File ): Observable<any> {
    console.log(file);
    let url = this.config.getConfig("serviceEndpoints").importRepostory;
    url = this.formatString(url, { repoid: repoId, file: file });
    console.log(url);

    return this.http.post(url, null)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);

const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'TARGET_API_URL', fd, {
  reportProgress: true
});

this._http.request(req).pipe(...).subscribe(...); // Inject HTTP client in constructor.
```

For detail implementation: https://github.com/wannadream/angular-material-file-upload/blob/master/src/app/material-file-upload/material-file-upload.component.ts